# Several machines randomly hang with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware-failure, ubuntu-14.04, websocket

At work, I bought 40 panel-PC's (these: http://www.advantech.com/products/5a93b96b-91d6-4a66-b738-db5c65a85a38/utc-510d/mod_121eb06c-38fb-406a-9da3-9433caefd38f), and had someone to build a wooden case around them, with around 15-20cm opening in the bottom, slightly tilted.

Ubuntu 14.04 is supported, which I installed on all of them. Defaulted BIOS-settings. Stripped down the Ubuntu desktop version and tried as well a minimal server version (with no real server stuff running), both only to start Chrome, Firefox or Chromium in fullscreen upon startup, loading an internal web appliation with http(s) and a websockets connection. No keyboard nor mouse connected, just RJ45 and power.

The problem is: several setups die with no reasons at all - they just hang, the clock stops, totally non-responsive, without e.g stuff emitted from websockets. The only way to get them back on track is switching the power off and on again. Different setup every day, totally random, around 5-10 per day, with or without a browser at startup, just idle'ing (I turned off the screensavers, power saving stuff and all the updates to not "disturb" the running system). Installed apport, checked system messages - nothing.

As I am seriously run out of ideas, I need some more aspects regarding this -- how can I continue from here on? I sent two machines to the manufacturer as well to have them check stuff, but want to hunt this down in parallel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the latest LTS versions? 16.04 has been *very* reliable for me, and is similar to 14.04. 18.04 LTS has a different desktop, and might work better, too.

Comment: Have you monitored the CPU temperatures of the units?  Maybe they are overheating.  I note that hot air does not sink and these are described as fanless units.

Comment: 16.04 hung as well, tested that in an early state, @DrMoishePippik.

Comment: @davidgo, yes, I had that one going on as well, hung just with the CPU temp graph on the screen, on a decent level (35°C, 95°F).

Comment: @davidgo - let me correct this slightly: CPU's core-temps are at 55-58°C, 131-136°F), mainboard sensor shows around halv of this, still hangs, 0-2% CPU usage.

Comment: there must be something in the logs, post a snippet from just before one of them hangs.

Comment: @DeclanGallagher Just my thought. From which one would be the best to post here?

Comment: @chr_lt_ney 14.04 isn't using systemd I dont think, so /var/log/syslog? I believe it is? /var/log/messages on most but i think its syslog on ubuntu. Please just show the output right up until you reboot a machine

Comment: @DeclanGallagher, you were right there, here it is, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b58zH7WhvHnUgnNS99y1x_kHEzLPBr2_/view?usp=sharing - it's huge though. System hung latest 20:06 on Jul 13, but there's no such line. Have a look please.